# How to properly va_end?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

```
#include <cstdarg>
using namespace std;

void do_something( va_list numbers, int count ) {
//                         ^
// Should I call this by reference here? I mean, va_list & numbers?
    //... stuff
    va_end( numbers );
}

void setList( int count, ... ) {
    va_list numbers;
    va_start( numbers, count );
    do_something( numbers, count );
}

int main() {
    setList( 2, 0, 1 );
    return 0;
}
```

When taking `va_list` to another function, how should I pass it to that function? I know that `va_end` must be called when things are done with `va_list` I'm confused whether I should call it by reference or not. Will `va_list` be properly ended even though it is not called by reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Variable argument lists:**

You should never use `va_end` in a function taking the `va_list` as argument!

From the (Linux) man-page for `va_arg`:

> Each invocation of va_start() must be matched by a corresponding
>   invocation of va_end() in the **same function**.

(Emphasis mine)

In a function having a `va_list` argument, take the `va_list` by value (as C-library functions like `vprintf`, ... do, too).

**Example:**

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

void v_display_integers(int count, va_list ap) {
    while(0 < count--) {
        int i = va_arg(ap, int);
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}

void display_integers(int count, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, count);
    v_display_integers(count, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    // You might use 'va_start' and 'va_end' a second time, here.
    // See also 'va_copy'.
}

int main() {
    display_integers(3, 0, 1, 2);
}
```

**Note:**

In C++ you should avoid variable argument lists. Alternatives are `std::array`, `std::vector`,`std::initializer_list` and variadic templates.

Comment: To help remember this,, you can imagine that `va_start` might `malloc` some space and `va_end` might `free` it

Comment: @M.M: Except, `malloc` and `free` can (and often will) be called in different functions.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to call va_end in the same function in which I called va_start or va_copy, like any other resource allocation/deallocation pair. That style is required by the standard, although some implementations are more tolerant.

Normally, va_lists are passed by value. They are small objects.

Answer (score 1):

The macro function `va_end` is implemented as either void statement or resetting the `va_list` variable.

> http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/include/stdarg.h.htm

Theoretically, you can call it anywhere, or even skip it. However, to be a good programmer, we need to put it after the `va_` functions